# If the Simulacrum spell is cast on a Divination Wizard that currently has Portent rolls stored, does the Simulacrum also have those Portent rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, simulacrum

Essentially, I'm not sure "where" stored Portent rolls "exist" while not in use.

The [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell description says:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed without any equipment. Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates, except that it is a construct.

The [Divination wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofDivination)'s [Portent](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Portent-426) feature (PHB, p. 116) reads as follows:

> When you finish a long rest, roll two d20s and record the numbers rolled. You can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check made by you or a creature that you can see with one of these foretelling rolls. You must choose to do so before the roll, and you can replace a roll in this way only once per turn.
>
> Each foretelling roll can be used only once. When you finish a long rest, you lose any unused foretelling rolls.

Presumably, if you used Simulacrum on a creature with the Lucky feat, the resulting simulacrum would be created with Luck points (the same number that the original creature had at the time of casting). Does Simulacrum interact with Portent in the same way?

Comment: Can you tell why you are presuming the carrying over of luck points? Is there something that eludes to the that specifically?

Comment: @KelvintheWizard Because luck points are uses/long rest that get expended. Portent Rolls are already determined at the end of a long rest and can be spent in a very meta way. This question is asking if the Simulacrum has the same rolls at creation not if they can use the ability at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### I would say: Yes and No

I can't find any specific rules one way or the other, but *portent* is a mechanic for the divination wizard receiving

> glimpses of the future..

So I would say that the simulacrum actually has the same glimpses of the future since it presumably takes all the memories of the original person.

Therefore I would rule that the 2 Portent rolls can be used by either the caster or the simulacrum, but there remain 2 rolls, and 2 uses, rather than 4 uses.

The explanation might be that the caster sees a vision in the morning of his simulacrum avoiding some kind of danger, and the simulacrum is fully aware of this, so is allowed to use the roll. The simulacrum didn't get its own visions however.

The following morning however I would certainly give the simulacrum its own rolls. I can however see this being rules in many different ways, and this is just what I think makes the most sense given the 'fluff' around Portent.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any other feature in which a die roll (or other value) gets "stored" in a way similar to the Portent feature?

Comment: @casce not off the top of my head

Comment: This interpretation makes sense, but it's only one possible interpretation. Regardless, the fact is, it's clearly not RAW. The mechanics for a simulacrum are well defined. If a wizard has portent rolls of 5 and 17 and creates a simulacrum before using one, the simulacrum has its own 5 and 17 rolls.

Comment: Note that the player rolling portent dice after a long rest is just how the feature is implemented mechanically. It doesn't mean the character is necessarily having two glimpses of the future every time they wake up. It makes at least as much sense to assume the glimpses of the future are occurring immediately prior to the events in question. In this case, there would be no reason to alter the standard rules for a simulacrum.

Answer (score 3):

## The Simulacrum has its own Portents, independently from the original

The *simulacrum* spell says:

> [...] Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates, except that it is a construct.

The RAW here is clear. The simulacrum is independent of the original as far as existing as a creature, with its own class features, spell slots, HP, and the rest of its statistics. Those statistics include Portent dice. Granted, it is a duplicate of its original (it will have the same rolls), but it still exists as a separate entity.

Imagine two players rolling their own Diviners. After each long rest, will they share the same two uses of Portent? No, because their pool of Portents is not shared. The same applies to a simulacrum - treat it as though it was a second character, because it is.

### What about seeing the "same glimpses of the future" line?

Portents are supposed to be vague, from their fluff. The idea is, for example, if you roll a natural 1 and a natural 20, you might get an overwhelming feeling of strong victory, but you don't know what form specifically those victories will take later that day. Only when you elect to use the portent to grant your paladin a natural 20 on their smite do you get to say, "Oh! That makes sense, that's what that brilliant flash of light I saw in my vision means!"; or when you cause someone to fail their save, that can be the only time you can say, "Right, that vision of a faceless person falling down a hole makes sense now, because this guy fell into my trap!"

That means, even if the simulacrum sees the same vision, those visions can represent different things. There is enough room and vagueness that the fluff does not necessarily override the mechanics, which is that the simulacrum gets its own copy of everything the original Diviner has.